# Can I connect a PAL Xbox 360 to a PC TFT LCD monitor?

Tags: xbox-360, monitor

Can all flat panel TFT LCD monitors decode both PAL and NTSC? I have a PAL Xbox 360 and I am now living in America. When I connect it to my TV, it shows only in black and white.

So, I would like to try to connect it to a PC monitor.  But, before I splash out the cash to buy the cable to connect my Xbox 360 to my monitor, I would like to know if it works?

And, regional issues I should be worried about?

Comment: All I want to know is if it will show coloured on my flat panel tft lcd PC monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your monitor won't care about PAL or NTSC. As for connecting it to your TV, you could find out if your TV has the option of swapping between PAL and NTSC.

As for regional issues, there will be some potential issues but [this chart](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Region_Free_Xbox_360_Games) should provide you with enough information to help decide on what games to buy from where.

Answer (score 0):

More modern monitors will have an HDMI port so assuming you have a slightly newer Xbox 360 you could use an HDMI cable.

That aside a computer monitor won't know the difference between NTSC and PAL so you should be fine.  Keep in mind that you will need to output the sound somehow too, so you will need to either get some speakers that will accept a component input or alternatively you can get a little converter so you could use headphones or normal speakers.

Comment: A lot of monitors nowadays have built in speakers